# How to replace XML with Java?

Tags: java, reflection, java-compiler-api

I don't understand worldwide fashion to use XML for storing settings, page or GUI layouts and even bean sets.

If we take into account the fact, that XML is not a single language, but a template to define multiple languages, the mass insanity become obvious.

Why use DOZENS of languages instead of using some ONE?

For example, Java.

It can define or declare any type of GUI hierarchy, setting tables and so on.

So why don't we use java files to store all things?

For example, one could provide settings file in java format like this:

```
class Properties {

   String dbpassword = "password";

   String database = "localhost";

   String dbuser = "mkyong";

}
```

The this file could be compiled on the fly by runtime compiler and fields extracted by reflection.

So, why don't we do so?

The only reason coming in mind is security.

External file could contain not only properties but some constructor code, which could hack the application or crash it.

So. Is there any protection for this case? Can we limit possible functionality of runtime compiled files?

**UPDATE**

I don't mean namely Java. Java is just a sample. I need ways to use single language.

**UPDATE 2**

I claim, that it would be better to use one single language for entire project aspects.

Suppose that in MVC pattern we would use three separate languages for model, view and controller! This would be nonsense! We use single language. I mean we people use different languages, but each one programmer uses one single language still separating MVC. This is what configuration files are: the separation of one more concept. No any sense to use different language just because concept was separated.

This also applies to HTML / JavaScript / CSS. No sense to have three languages. No any damned sense!

Of course I understand historical reasons etc. But these are no sense, these are just pesky reasons.

So, why then we are seeing new and new projects with the same nature?

Why did MS created XAML for WPF? They made new fresh C# language, why not to put XAML into it too?

Why did Oracle created FXML for JavaFX? Thanks God they abandoned JavaFX script! Because they wanted to have THREE languages for just RIA!

Comment: Simply, as there are systems/applications/frameworks which are not based on Java?! Ask a VB6 developer to include Java code - I hope you know what I mean

Comment: JSON would be a better choice for your concerns. But even then, Lisp and Scheme programmers will still shake their heads in dismay...

Comment: @NedNowotny there is already a [draft-version for json-schema](http://json-schema.org/) available, but it has its limits like missing object-orientated-like inheritance. You can bypass this with "including" `allOf` a definition (like f.e. a message) but you can't override something which is defined there - the json-message which is validated has to survive both validation checks, against the origin json schema and the referred one. If however the referred one includes something like `"addidionalProperties": false` validation will with high probability fail for extended parameters

Comment: XML is not a programming language, and Java is.

Comment: @Vottner XML when used with validation through an XML Schema -- or Relax NG -- is indeed more useful than JSON as a structured data format. JSON-Schema may change that. However, Lisp and Scheme used S-Expressions for programs and data, as long ago as the 1960s. S-Expressions are as easy, if not easier to parse, as XML in languages without direct support for S-expression parsing and are considerably less verbose. XML was a decent idea, but has proven unnecessarily painful to use in practice, and has been considerably less than ideal when used as a data interchange or configuration file format.

Answer (score 2):

The comments have identified one possible explanation:

> A Java syntax would be hard to deal with from other languages.

... though for the configuration properties of Java program, this seems a bit of a stretch.  (Why would you read a Java program's config properties from a non-Java program?)

I think the real reason nobody does what you propose is that it introduces some *new* problems which make your solution as bad as doing XML configs the "hard way".

- The person writing the configs needs to understand Java syntax.
- If they make a mistake, the application has to deal with a Java compilation error in the middle of starting the application.
- Accessing the properties would entail the application programmer writing of reflective code.  This code is typically fragile, and writing it would be as hard as writing a bunch of DOM-walking code to read stuff from a parsed XML configuration file.

---

Now maybe XML is not the best choice for configuration files.  These days, I'd prefer classic "Properties" file syntax or JSON.

But it XML is OK too, if you do it *the right way*.  For example:

- If you use a Java / XML binding library (e.g. [JAXB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding)) you don't need to write an XML parser, or a bunch of gnarly DOM-walking code to pick information out a parse tree.
- You can uses a DTD or XML schema driven editor so that the user doesn't need to write (or even see) raw XML files.
- If your configs are *really* complicated, you could use something like EMF to model them and then *generate* DTDs / Schemas and all of the Java code for the config accessor libraries and customizable application-specific config editors.

---

For the record, the approach that you proposed is commonly used in scripting languages like Perl, Ruby, Python and even "sh".  It just that it tends to be problematic in statically compiled languages.

---

Re your followup "Why did XXX do YYY" questions:

1. I don't know.  I wasn't in the room.
2. My opinions would be pure speculation.
3. It doesn't make any difference *why* they did it anyway.

And in response to your general "it doesn't make sense" comment/complaint, the IT world is rife with pragmatic compromises / clunky solutions.  Complaining about it doesn't achieve anything.  If you want to achieve something, try your way out, and *show us the evidence* that it really works in Java.

Comment: Your three reasons applicable to any language, including `XML` and `JSON` (person need to know JSON/XML, person can make mistake and dial with mistaken file, accessing JSON/XML requires writing parsing code).

Comment: @SuzanCioc - By my point is 1) you've not gained anything, and 2) there are *better* ways to handle the XML that *don't* involve those things.

Comment: I guess, if there is a one-for-all solution for everything we would obviously already use it, but as this is not the case we'll have to agree on certain IIOP standards to enable communication with different or even legacy systems. And you can't obligate everybody to agree on the same standard - moreover, some will always interpret it in an other way or try to dominate the development process with their "concepts" of what everyone will need (`"640 kb are enough for anyone"`)

Comment: Simple "property" files which can be "parsed" by reading a line at a time and using something like `split` on an `=` or `:` character are dead simple, generally easy to read and edit, and work for many things and across virtually all programming languages. However, more structure can be required to reflect semantic relationships among data which are, at best, inconvenient to express in a property file. That is where JSON, XML, or S-expressions can help. As for Java source code or any other compiled language syntax, they are fine for compiled defaults, but not for configuration files.

Comment: @StephenC I gain that I use one single language for all. Suppose that in MVC pattern we would use three separate languages for model, view and controller! This would be nonsense! We use single language. I mean we people use different languages, but each one programmer uses one single language still separating MVC. This is what configuration files are: the separation of one more concept. No any sense to use different language just because concept was separated.

Comment: @SuzanCioc - You are entitled to your opinions.  I'm just giving you the reasons why (I think) people don't do this in Java.  Feel free to *show* us that we are wrong ... but not on my project thanks :-)

Comment: @SuzanCioc - If you have time to spend on this kind of thing, take a look at "orthogonal persistence".  It is a good example a brilliant unifying idea that that was tried, and tried, and tried ... and ultimately given up on.  Because it was impractical.

Answer (score 0):

Using executable code for configuration is a recipe for disaster.  Consider:

```
class Properties 
{
    String dbpassword = "password";
    String database = "localhost";
    String dbuser = "mkyong";

    static
    {
        File userDir = new File("c:\\users\\mkyong");
        userDir.delete();
        //etc...
    }
}
```

You can try to counter this by using a security manager to limit damage, but they are not perfect.  Or you could write your own parser that only accepts a sub-set of what a full Java program can do (limited API, no APIs, etc. similar to JSON vs full Javascript).  But at the end of the day, is the Java syntax any better than the other configuration file formats?